# How to get the datediff value in ascending order in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have date as per below table. I want to compare the minimum date in the Date table with itself first and the diff a 0 , then min date with next higher date and diff as 1 and then so on till the min date compare with the current date as diff accordingly which is mentioned in (What I want table)

All I was able to get the Datediff in reverse order when I am using the below formula

```
= DATEDIFF('Table'[Date], TODAY(), DAY)
```

I tried to reverse the TODAY() and 'Table'[Date] but all it did is that it appended '-' in front of Datediff values.

```
Date        Datediff   WhatI want
01/04/2020  28          0
22/04/2020  7           21
23/04/2020  6           22
24/04/2020  5           23
25/04/2020  4           24
26/04/2020  3           25
27/04/2020  2           26
28/04/2020  1           27
29/04/2020  0           28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you only want those 2 columns in your table and created the following measure:

```
Result = 
VAR __minDate = CALCULATE( MIN( 'Table'[Date] ), ALLSELECTED('Table'[Date] ) )
Return DATEDIFF( __minDate, MIN('Table'[Date]), DAY )
```

This should be the expected result if that is the case:

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Wow.. its worked perfect, exactly the same as I was expecting. Thanks a lot Agustin.